# pd.period_range(...) equivalent function in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have to generate 'yearquarter' combinations within a specific date.

example:

```
start_date = '2021-01-30'
end_date =   '2022-05-01'
```

Output:

```
result = [ '2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2021Q4', '2022Q1', '2022Q2' ]
```

In python we have a function which does the similar task,

```
pd.period_range(pd.to_datetime(stdate), pd.to_datetime(eddate), freq='Q')
```

Is there anything equivalent in SQL to do this, I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This requires MySQL 8.0 because of the common table expression:

```
with recursive cte (date) as (
  select '2021-01-30'
  union
  select date + interval 3 month from cte
  where date < '2022-05-01' - interval 3 month
)
select concat(year(date), 'Q', quarter(date)) as result
from cte;
```

Output:

```
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| 2021Q1 |
| 2021Q2 |
| 2021Q3 |
| 2021Q4 |
| 2022Q1 |
| 2022Q2 |
+--------+
```